# How do I remove rows from a DataTable based on the rows from another DataTable using Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 .Net DataTables. The tables both have the same column definitions.
How do I remove all the rows in Table1 that exist in Table2?

I know I can do this using nested foreach() loops and comparing the ItemArrays.

How would I do this using either Linq or a Lambda expression?